# I don't know why it don't send me a report message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I am making a report command with discord.py rewrite branch so here's some code.

```
@bot.command()
async def report(args):
    report_channel = bot.message.guild
    report = bot.message.guild
    await report_channel.send(f"Report sended with reason provided {args}")
    server = bot.get_guild(794541486083145729)
    channel = server.get_channel(809009106148130877)
    await channel.send(f"Report from {report} is reported with reason {args}")
```

but it just dont send any message. Instead it just give me error. wit this
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'message'
What is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in `ctx`. Try this out:

```py
@bot.command()
async def report(ctx, args):
    report = ctx.guild
    await ctx.send(f"Report sended with reason provided {args}")
    server = bot.get_guild(794541486083145729)
    channel = bot.get_channel(809009106148130877)
    await channel.send(f"Report from {report} is reported with reason {args}")
```

Just run your code normally with this command, and it should work.

Comment: @mooping please accept this answer if it works for you!